# "K-transformed" permutations

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, permutation

I have been banging my head against this problem for days, and searched exhaustively online for any hints on how to solve it. If you enjoy mathematically oriented programming problems, please take a look!

Here is the [problem (PDF courtesy of UVA)](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/120/12000.pdf):

> Consider a sequence of n integers < 1 2 3 4 ... n >. Since all the values are distinct, we know that there are n factorial permutations. A permutation is called K-transformed if the absolute difference between the original position and the new position of every element is at most K. Given n and K, you have to find out the total number of K-transformed permutations.

...

> Input:
>    The first line of input is an integer T (T < 20) that indicates the number of test cases.  Each case consists of a line containing two integers n and K. (1 <= n <= 10^9) and (0 <= K <= 3).
>
> Output:
>   For each case, output the case number first followed by the required result. Since the result could be huge, output result modulo 73405.

The problem setter, [Sohel Hafiz](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~shafiz/programming.htm), categorized this problem as "[Fast Matrix Exponentiation](http://www.google.com/search?q=Fast%20Matrix%20Exponentiation)." Unfortunately, the google search I linked here doesn't appear to bring up any relevant links besides a Wikipedia page thick with mathematical jargon and notation (Wikipedia has proven to me to be a poor replacement for any math textbook).

Here's what I've done so far:

This code will compute by recursion the number of K-transformed permutations for low values of n and k, but is far too complex. It is good enough to build a table for searching for patterns:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int permute(int * a, int size, int i, int k)
{
  int j;
  int total = 0;
  int x = size-i;
  int low=0;
  int high=size;
  if (i == 0)
  {
/*    for (j=0;j<size;j++)
      printf("%d, ", a[j]);
    printf("\n");
*/    return 1;
  }
  if (x-k>0)
    low = x-k;
  if (x+k+1<size)
    high = x+k+1;
  for (j=low;j<high;j++)
  {
    int b[size];
    memcpy(b,a,size*sizeof(int));
    if (b[j] == 0)
    {
      b[j] = x+1;
      total += permute(b,size,i-1,k);
    }
  }
  return total;
}

int main() 
{
  int n, k, j, y, z;
  int * arr;
  /*scanf("%d %d", &n,&k);*/ k=2;
  for (n=0;n<14;n++)
  {
    int empty[n];
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
      empty[j] = 0;
    arr = empty;  
    z = permute(arr, n, n, k);
    y = magic(n,k);
    printf("%d %d\n",z, y);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The first thing I figured out was that k=1 is clearly the Fibonacci sequence.
The magic function in main here is something I figured out later, almost by accident. It works ONLY for k=2, but it is exact up to n=14.

```
int magic(int n, int k)
{
  if (n<0)
    return 0;
  if (n==0)
    return 1;
  if (n==1)
    return 1;
  return 2*magic(n-1,k) + 2*magic(n-3,k) - magic(n-5,k);  
}
```

Very weird! I don't know the significance of this function, but it can be simplified to run in a loop in order to run just fast enough to finish K=2 for values up to 10^9.

All that's remaining is to find a non-recursive equation that can find any value for K=3 in a reasonable amount of time (under 10s).

**EDIT:** I am interested in the algorithm used to solve the problem for any given n and k within a reasonable amount of time. I do not expect anyone to actually confirm that their algorithm works by writing code to the specifications of the contest rules, what I'm looking for in an answer is a description of how to approach the problem and apply numerical methods to reach a solution.

Comment: @MAK: I think given the clear declaration in the title and the fact that the OP already put some effort into finding a solution himself, this doesn't count as cheating. And sometimes understanding a solution given to you does help to learn new angles to view the problem from.

Comment: @MAK Good point, the last line of the question was written hastily. I've replaced it to clarify what I'm looking for in an answer (at the time I didn't realize the complexity of the solution). So far MizardX has the best answer AND it doesn't giving away the solution. I plan on awarding him the bounty once I implement his matrix algorithm to confirm it works in a reasonable amount of time. I'm hesitant to try it in C, so I'll have to rewrite it in Java.

Comment: @Tozar: Great. I have removed my comments. Best of luck with the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *K* is low, it falls naturally on matrix exponentiation.

Each item can end up at most *K* positions from it's start position. This gives at most (2 *K* - 1) positions, but some positions could already be occupied. You can have 2<sup>2 *K* - 1</sup> possible configurations (of the closest (2 *K* -1) slots) when placing an item. Each new item in any unoccupied position would generate a new configuration, and a new, and a new...

You need to figure out how many ways you can get from each configuration to every other. You could use brute force for this, and save the values. When you know this, you can place the numbers in a matrix; Every column is the from-configuration, and every row is the to-configuration.

Consider a count-vector *v*; Each cell in it represents the number of ways to get to some configuration in *n* steps. Start with the initial count-vector (all zeros, except for one 1 representing the empty configuration, *n* = 0). If you multiply this vector with the matrix (*v* x *A*), you will move those counts ahead one step (*n* = 1). Repeat for additional steps.

Now comes the interesting part. If you multiply this matrix with itself (*A* x *A*), you will get a matrix for moving two generations ahead. Again (*A*<sup>2</sup> x *A*<sup>2</sup>) and you will get a matrix for moving 4 generations. You can use this technique to move it several thousand (or million) generations ahead, in just a few iterations.

You can read more about [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on Wikipedia.

---

If the above is too slow, you can try to find a recurrence relation for the values you find. Take the first few values of the sequence, and place them in an equation system:

> *a* · *x*<sub>1</sub> + *b* · *x*<sub>2</sub> = *x*<sub>3</sub>
>   *a* · *x*<sub>2</sub> + *b* · *x*<sub>3</sub> = *x*<sub>4</sub>

Solve for *a* and *b*. Then to generate the sequence, you multiply the last two numbers with *a* and *b* and add to get the next.

If this doesn't reproduce the sequence, you can increase the size:

> *a* · *x*<sub>1</sub> + *b* · *x*<sub>2</sub> + *c* · *x*<sub>3</sub> = *x*<sub>4</sub>
>   *a* · *x*<sub>2</sub> + *b* · *x*<sub>3</sub> + *c* · *x*<sub>4</sub> = *x*<sub>5</sub>
>   *a* · *x*<sub>3</sub> + *b* · *x*<sub>4</sub> + *c* · *x*<sub>5</sub> = *x*<sub>6</sub>

Solve for *a*, *b* and *c*. Increase further until you get something that works. If you go one more step then, you should get an under-determined system.

It could happen that there are no recurrence relation (at least no linear one). In this case you could increase size, but you would never find anything that works.

---

To take a simple example. Let's consider *K* = 1. This will give us a neighborhood of size 3 (= 2 *K* + 1), and 8 distinct configurations (= 2<sup>2 *K* + 1</sup>).

To pick a notation, I'll use `#` for occupied or inaccessible, and `.` for free.

To generate the matrix, we must consider which patterns can be transformed into which by adding a single symbol.

- For patterns starting with a free slot, we must place the next symbol to the far left. Otherwise we would have a gap in the sequence.
- For the pattern `###`, we don't have any free spaces to place anything, so that is a dead-end.
- For the remaining patterns, can can place a symbol in any free spot, and then shift the pattern one space (moving to the next position).

The matrix could look like this:

```
    ... ..# .#. .## #.. #.# ##. ###
...  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
..#  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
.#.  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
.##  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
#..  0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
#.#  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
##.  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
###  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As a starting pattern, we will take `#..`. This is because we can't place the first symbol before the start of the sequence. A sequence of one symbol, can only be written in one way, so the starting count-vector becomes `0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0`.

The final pattern we want is `#..`. No symbol beyond the end of the sequence, but the remaining must be filled. The pattern is that after the shift. This means we want to look at position 5 in the vector (counting from 1).

The first few values we get are:

```
n   p(n,1)
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        5
5        8
6       13
7       21
8       34
```

Of course, much of the matrix is redundant. You could spend some time to eliminate rows and columns. I won't demonstrate this.

Once we have a few values, we can try to find the recurrence relation. First let's try a system of size 1:

> 1·*a* = 2

This would solve to *a* = 2. But if we try the next value, we will see that if fails already on the next value:

> 2·*a* = 2·2 = 4 ≠ 3.

Next, lets try a system of size 2:

> 1·*a* + 2·*b* = 3
>   2·*a* + 3·*b* = 5

This solves to *a* = *b* = 1. This will actually generate the whole sequence.

> 3·*a* + 5·*b* = 3·1 + 5·1 = 8
>   5·*a* + 8·*b* = 5·1 + 8·1 = 13
>   ...

If we try an even bigger system, we will run into problems:

> 1·*a* + 2·*b* + 3·*c* = 5
>   2·*a* + 3·*b* + 5·*c* = 8
>   3·*a* + 5·*b* + 8·*c* = 13

This solves to *a* = 1 - *c*, *b* = 2 - *c*, without any value for *c*.

If we try the sequence for *K* = 2 (generated with the above method): 1 2 6 14 31 73 172 400 932 2177

This won't give a valid solution until size 5: *a* = -1, *b* = 0, *c* = 2, *d* = 0, *e* = 2. This is the same relation as you found.

Comment: Excellent answer! I'll try this tomorrow. Is there an easy way to find recurrence relations? I was seriously considering writing a C program to do this earlier today, but I wasn't sure if it would work. The recurrence relation for k=2 is 2*x5 + 2*x3 - x1 = x6 in case you missed it in the question. It seems fairly complex compared to k=1 so I don't know what to expect for k=3.

Comment: Couldn't figure this out... still looking for an answer!

Comment: I wrote a program to search for a recurrence relation, but k=3 is far too complex to just guess. The program worked to find k=1 and k=2 (up to n=8, I may need to go back and find more value of n to see if it's still valid for larger value of n).

Comment: @Tozar Added an example of both the matrix generation, and recurrence relation finding.

Comment: Recurrence relation for *K* = 3 actually has 14 coefficients. (Only two of which are zero.)

Comment: WOW, well no wonder I didn't find it. How might someone go about solving such a large system of equations in a programming contest setting (1 computer, no internet, no software not provided on a stripped down OS)?

Comment: Since it is a linear system, Gaussian Elimination would work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Row_reduction

Comment: Interestingly though you assume the existence of a recursion formula, its pretty easy to prove that one exists, and determine a maximum bound on its order. First the Matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial (by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem), which is of order 2^{2K+1}, i.e. sum k_i M^i = 0. Now the terms we're interested in can be expressed as a_n = u^T M^n v . Finally sum k_i a_i = sum k_i u^T M^i v = u^T ( sum k_i M^i ) v = 0. Thus the coefficients in the recursion formula are actually the coefficients in the characteristic polynomial of M (with some sign rearagngement).

Comment: Sorry for the ugly inline maths. Didn't think it warranted a separate answer and didn't want to edit itinto your answer.

Comment: @MizardX I finally solved the problem thanks to your help! Writing a function for matrix exponentiation turned out to be the hardest part since I used C and my pointer intuition has yet to be completely refined. Lots of seg faults. Know of any good techniques for Matrix multiplication mid-competition (preferably using built in libraries)?

Answer (score 6):

There are two parts to the problem.  First is figuring out the recurrence formula for `k=0, 1, 2, 3`.  The second part is calculating values for large `n` using the recurrence formula.

For the first part:

Let `p(n, k)` be the number of permutations of `n` elements that are `k`-transformed.
When `k=0` the recurrence is just `p(n, 0) = 1`.

For `k=1`, first consider where 1 goes in the permutation.  It either goes in position 1 or position 2.  If it goes in position 1, then the remaining elements are just the original problem with `n-1` elements.  So we have `p(n, 1) = p(n-1, 1) + ...`.  If the first element goes in position 2, then what?  In this case the second element has to go into position 1.  At this point you have the original problem with `n-2` elements.  So the recurrence is `p(n, 1) = p(n-1, 1) + p(n-2, 1)` which is the Fibonacci sequence.

For `k=2` and `k=3` you get more possibilities but the reasoning is the same. [still working out exact recurrences]

The second part is computing the solution to the recurrences for large values of `n`.  For this you put the recurrence into matrix form and do repeated squaring/multiplying to get high powers of the matrix.  For the `k=1` case the matrix is:

```
A = [0 1]
    [1 1]
```

To get `p(n + 2, 1)` you need to compute `A^n * [1, 1]`.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is the lack of information for k=3. Higher value of k have complex recurrence relations (take a look at the one in my question for k=2)!

Comment: There is no easy recursive formula for k = 3 ... check my answer